# Specifying range in VBA macros

Tags: excel, vba

I am really new to VBA. SO this might seem a silly question for experts.

after researching the internet on how to put dynamic range for filters in excel considering a situation when your list might grow or shrink I stumbled on couple of ways. One of them is as the following.

ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=46, Criteria1:="1"

I know the you can put two arguments to specify ranges and the second one is optional. In this particular I am just putting the first cell where my data starts. My questions are below:

1. does the code automatically select the active range based on the first specified cell?
2. Had my data started from "C5" would i still have to chose the argument as "A1"?
3. I am filtering out something from column 46. what does it matter where I specify my first cell? for example if I had chosen "C5" instead of "A1" how it would have affected my macro?
4. Let's say, I want to filter out something from column 2 ie, Field 2. But the argument for range I choose as "D5". How it would affect my macro code?

Comment: My answer is to find out for yourself! Testing this yourself will allow you to actually see what happens when you tweak the available options available to you from the `Range.Autofilter` method. While we could show you, doing it yourself is a great learning exp and you are much more likely to remember the results after seeing them.

Answer (score 0):

## AutoFilter: A Small Study

- Well, I was curious, too. So I studied it a little bit and created a
  workbook where you can input the parameters of some of the arguments
  of the `AutoFilter` method and just by clicking on a command button
  apply the changes. The next click removes the filter.
- The workbook also contains the results of the behavior when changing
  by row. The same thing could be done by column.
- [Workbook
  Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d8rycf7mtc269uf/specifying-range-in-vba-macros_55304876.xlsm?dl=0)
  (Dropbox)

The following image displays the initial state of the only worksheet in the workbook.

[image]

This I was most curious about: what would happen if I would filter in `C8`. There's a surprise.

[image]

There still remains a ton of unanswered questions, but this could get you started to investigate deeper.